# Vime.js (angular) custom player setup falls back to defaults on mobile but works on desktop

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-video

I'm building a custom video player as an Angular component using [Vime.js library](https://vimejs.com/).

I've set up what I need and everything works well on desktop.

However, when I run my app on a mobile device, all my settings get ignored and I see default controls and visuals.

Below is the code I've used to set up the desktop version:

```js
          <vm-player autoplay muted>
            <vm-video cross-origin>
              <source [attr.data-src]="message.contentLink" type="video/mp4" />
            </vm-video>


            <vm-ui no-settings no-controls>

              <vm-icon-library
                name="custom"
                [resolver]="customResolver"
              ></vm-icon-library>

                <vm-controls>


                  <div class="controls-container">
                    <vm-playback-control
                      icons="custom"
                      playIcon="play"
                      pauseIcon="heart"
                    ></vm-playback-control>

                    <div class="timeline-container">
                      <vm-time-progress separator="/"></vm-time-progress>
                      <vm-scrubber-control></vm-scrubber-control>
                    </div>

                    <div class="other-controls">
                      <vm-volume-control></vm-volume-control>
                      <vm-fullscreen-control></vm-fullscreen-control>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </vm-controls>
            </vm-ui>
          </vm-player>
```

I have no idea why my setup works only on desktop.

Is there a way to make the Vime player look the same on desktop and on mobile?